# How to get Div element Value

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a div

```
<div id="claimamount"></div>
```

Which gets value from javascript

```
 var directTime = <?=($domedo)?>;
```

Which outputs as

```
<div id="claimamount">50</div>
```

This div is inside a form and when I submit form I need to get value from this div as $_POST

How I can get this value on form submission

Comment: you need `input` tag! not `div`

Comment: <input type="text" value="50">

Comment: @john if you are stuck with div, then you need to manipulate form submission with javascript and you can fetch the html value with javascript like this var text = $('#fclaimamount').text().

Comment: That JS just assigns `directtime` to the PHP value. Where do you modify the DOM with it? Where is your form and submitting part?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is using input instead of div, but you can add input contain value of div when form submission. In this case value of created input sended.

```
<form id="myfrom">
  <div id="claimamount">50</div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
$("form").submit(function(e){
  var val = $("#claimamount").text();  
  $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "divValue").attr('value', val).appendTo('#myfrom');
  return true;
});
```

Comment: You get one part right but I need to get value as $_POST instead of jquery form submission better need in php

Comment: @john if the form is with `method="post"`, this will work just fine.

Comment: I am getting error Notice: Undefined index: ClaimAmount in   ... i think there is no predefined value as this div element gets value dynamically from javasscript var so do we need to define val in it?

Comment: @john You should get post value by `$_POST` array. Name of input is key of array. In the code you should use `$_POST["divValue"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper to add some element contents to your form

```
function sendElementContent(elementId, form) {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.name = elementId;
  input.value = document.getElementById(elementId).textContent;
  input.type = 'hidden';
  form.appendChild(input);
}
```

Usage

```
sendElementContent('claimamount', document.querySelector('form'));
```

It will add an hidden input with the `div#claimamount` content. You can retrieve the value in `$_POST["claimamount"]`

Non reusable version :

```
<script>
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var claimamountDiv = document.querySelector('#claimamount');
form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
   var input = document.createElement('input');
   input.type = 'hidden';
   input.name ='claimamount';
   input.value  = claimamountDiv.textContent;
   form.appendChild(input);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I am not good in php can you tell me how to use 'usage' part in my page and fucntion should be added in that php page also?

Comment: This is not PHP but Javascript code, I made you an edit with a complete code, you just have to add the script in your page, that's all

Comment: `$bonval =   $_POST['ClaimAmount']; ` results in 
Notice: Undefined index: ClaimAmount in /